# Animating a datafile with gnuplot without using datablocks

Tags: animation, gnuplot

If I have a datafile that is simply

```
x y
0 0
1 1
2 2
3 3
4 4
```

for example, where each line is a new timestep, **how can I create an animation of this with gnuplot**?

The desired animation in this case would be a point moving one unit in the positive x direction and one unit in the positive y direction each timestep.

I've only read examples of how to do this when each timestep is in a new 'datablock'. In this case, the datafile would look like

```
x y

0 0


1 1


2 2


3 3


4 4
```

which seems silly and would mean that I cannot easily use that same datafile to plot x vs y in most programs.

---

I've noticed an utter dearth of gnuplot examples or syntax explanations online. Am I missing some good resources?

Comment: Hard to answer this when you don't explain what you are trying to plot or what distinguishes each frame in the animation from the previous one.  The data format normally has nothing to do with animation.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, @EthanMerritt. I've edited the post to include what my intention for animation of the example data would be.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First determine what the desired range is on x and y.  You will keep this range for the entire animation.

```
set xrange [ xmin : xmax ]
set yrange [ ymin : ymax ]

do for [n=1:*] {
    plot 'data' using 1:2 every 1::n::n with points
    pause 1
}
```

This will plot one point every second until it runs off the end of the file. After the last line of your file you will just get an error message every second until you kill it.

Both the user manual and worked demos are on-line at gnuplot.info.  They should also somewhere in the installed gnuplot package although exactly where they end up probably depends on your OS configuration.